# Pipe subprocess to a file in Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl

I'm beating my head against a wall trying to get my code to work properly. In essence, I've written a python script that will be called by cron. The script is to run once per week to perform database maintenance. My python script will call a perl script that performs the actual maintenance. I've had to build it this way because the perl script will be run a total of 9 separate times. There are 3 different categories of DB items and each category requires 3 different actions from the perl script. If a single action in any category fails, the script is to break from that category and move to the next one (each action is dependent upon the previous action).

My script is failing to execute properly and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to troubleshoot it but my logging logic isn't working properly either. The only output I get in my log file is the simple "print" commands that I've written into my script for notation and formatting.

I can run the perl script just fine from the CLI directly, but it fails to properly run when invoked from my python script.  Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

EDIT:
In response to a question, I don't have a good explanation of how the perl script is failing. I'm not getting the stdout or stderr from the perl script into my log file so I don't yet know why it's failing.
I didn't create the perl script, it was provided with the software suite that I'm administering.

Here's the log file output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Weekly Voyence archival, deletion, and purging of jobs, events, and revisions beginning at 14:46:11
Block failed, continuing to next block
------
Block failed, continuing to next block
------
Block failed, continuing to next block
------
Weekly Voyence archival, deletion, and purging of jobs, events, and revisions complete at 14:46:11
```

Here is output from running the perl script from the CLI (without errors):

```
Script started at Mon Nov  7 14:59:53 2016

Archving/Pruning 0 Parent jobs older than 90 days...
Archving/Pruning 0 Child Jobs older than 90 days...

No Records avaialble for archive..jobs Exiting
Script Completed.

The database utility console log can be found at /opt/voyence/tools/db-   utility/logs/dbutil_console.log

Script exited at Mon Nov  7 14:59:58 2016
```

Here is the python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
import time
import os
import subprocess
def SubProcessCaller(PATH,CallLoad,LogObj,LOGFILE):
    try:
        # subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/perl", "-i", "/opt/voyence/tools/db-    utility/database-utility.pl", CallLoad], stderr=LogObj.write, stdout=LogObj.write, shell=true)
        concatvar = "/usr/bin/perl -I /opt/voyence/tools/db-utility/common /opt/voyence/tools/db-utility/database-utility.pl" + CallLoad + " >> " + LOGFILE
        subprocess.check_output(concatvar.split(), shell=True)
        return True
    except:
        LogObj.write("Block failed, continuing to next block" "\n")
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #DECLARE VARIABLES AND OBJECTS
    TIME = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    PATH = "/opt/voyence/tools/db-utility/database-utility.pl"
    DATE = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    LOGFILE = "/var/log/voyence-archive/" + DATE + "voyence-archive.log"
    LOG = open(LOGFILE, "a+")
    #CREATE NEW LOG FILE
    LOG.write("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    LOG.write("Weekly Voyence archival, deletion, and purging of jobs, events, and revisions beginning at " + TIME + "\n")
    #JOB ARCHIVAL, DELETION, AND PURGING
    JobActionsDict = [" archive jobs 90"," delete jobs 90"," purge jobs 275"]
    #EVENT ARCHIVAL, DELETION, AND PURGING
    EventActionsDict = [" archive events all 90"," delete events all 90"," purge events all 275"]
    #REVISION ARCHIVAL, DELETION, AND PURGING
    RevisionActionsDict = [" archive revisions 40"," purge revisions 60","  delete revisions '3 months' 40"]

    ActionsTuple = (JobActionsDict, EventActionsDict, RevisionActionsDict)

    for dict in ActionsTuple:
        for item in dict:
            SPCBool = SubProcessCaller(PATH,item,LOG,LOGFILE)
            if SPCBool == False:
                break
        LOG.write("------\n")
    #CLOSE AFTER ALL LOGS HAVE BEEN WRITTEN
    LOG.write("Weekly Voyence archival, deletion, and purging of jobs, events, and revisions complete at " + TIME + "\n")
    LOG.close()
```

Comment: How is it failing? What is happening? Is there any output? You need to include more details. You can [edit] your question. You did not write the Perl program yourself, did you? It either was there already, or came with whatever software you are using.

Comment: `check_output` returns the output of the command, but that doesn't make much sense for a command that is already writing its output to a file. You can probably use `subprocess.call` instead.

Comment: @simbabque - Thanks for the feedback. I've added some additional details to answer your questions.

Comment: @chepner - I originally used subprocess.call which I thought I'd left commented out, but apparently I pulled it out of the script. The results with .call were the same as I'm getting from .check_output

Comment: Also, don't catch a bare exception or ignore the actual exception. Use `except Exception as exc:`, then at the very least write the exception to your log file (or directly to standard error) so you can see what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2):

```
concatvar = "/usr/bin/perl -I /opt/voyence/tools/db-utility/common /opt/voyence/tools/db-utility/database-utility.pl" + CallLoad + " >> " + LOGFILE
```

This concatenates the name of your program (`database-utility.pl`) with the contents of the `CallLoad` variable - without putting a space between them. So, unless the value in `CallLoad` starts with a space, you'll actually be looking for a program called `database-utility.plWhateverIsInCallLoad`.

Comment: Yeah I accounted for the spacing. Down in the actions dicts each argument that is passed up as a call load is preceded by a space.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I understand that this isn't causing your problem. But wouldn't it be better to put the space in the line I quoted above (where its presence would make sense) rather than in each individual argument (where its presence is a mystery)?

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree with your thought process. Your change makes a lot of sense. I think I'll incorporate that now.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but more idiomatic, Python. The major changes are to bypass the shell altogether when calling the Perl script, and to log any errors that might be raised by `subprocess.call` to aid in debugging the problem. (Consider using the `logging` module instead, but this has enough changes already.)

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
import time
import os
import subprocess

def subprocess_caller(path, call_load, log_obj):
    subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/perl",
                     "-I",
                     "/opt/voyence/tools/db-utility/common",
                     path,
                     call_load],
                     stdout=log_obj)

log_header = """\
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Weekly Voyence archival, deletion, and purging of jobs, events, and revisions beginning at %s
""" %(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #declare variables and objects
    path = "/opt/voyence/tools/db-utility/database-utility.pl"
    logfile = time.strftime("/var/log/voyence-archive/%Y%m%dvoyence-archive.log")

    #create new log file
    with open(logfile, "a+") as log:
        log.write(hog_header)
        #job archival, deletion, and purging
        job_actions = [" archive jobs 90"," delete jobs 90"," purge jobs 275"]
        #event archival, deletion, and purging
        event_actions = [" archive events all 90"," delete events all 90"," purge events all 275"]
        #revision archival, deletion, and purging
        revision_actions = [" archive revisions 40"," purge revisions 60","  delete revisions '3 months' 40"]

        actions = job_actions + event_actions + revision_action:

        for action_type in actions:
            for item in action_type:
                try:
                    subprocess_caller(path, item, log)
                except Exception as exc:
                    log_obj.write(exc + "\n")
                    log_obj.write("Block failed, continuing to next block\n")
                    break
                log.write("------\n")

        log.write("Weekly Voyence archival, deletion, and purging of jobs, events, and revisions complete at %s\n" %
                  (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prototype.  I've made a couple changes on my side to correct for a few errors that came up.  I've got what I believe to be a workable script on my dev box and I'll let it run as a cron job tonight to see how it behaves.  I'll let you know how it turns out.